# React Native Vision Camera - Bar Code Scanner crashes the android app

Tags: android, c++, react-native, barcode-scanner, react-native-vision-camera

I used `vision-camera-code-scanner` to scan bar codes. the code is working fine on IOS. but android it gives several errors including build fingerprint error. here is some error log of it.

```
> 02-14 00:17:17.605   494  2654 W libc    : Unable to set property "ctl.interface_start" to "com.qualcomm.qti.uceservice@2.3::IUceService/com.qualcomm.qti.uceservice": error code: 0x2002-14 00:17:18.604 25357 25378 W HidlServiceManagement: Waited one second for com.qualcomm.qti.uceservice@2.3::IUceService/com.qualcomm.qti.uceservice02-14 00:17:18.607   494  2655 W libc    : Unable to set property "ctl.interface_start" to "com.qualcomm.qti.uceservice@2.3::IUceService/com.qualcomm.qti.uceservice": error code: 0x2002-14 00:17:19.377  1556 23090 W ServiceManager: Permission failure: android.permission.CAMERA_OPEN_CLOSE_LISTENER from uid=10345 pid=182102-14 00:17:19.400  1821  2663 W libc    : Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"02-14 00:17:19.400  1821  2663 W CameraManagerGlobal: [soar.cts] ignore the status update of camera: 202-14 00:17:19.400  1821  2663 W libc    : Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"02-14 00:17:19.400  1821  2663 W CameraManagerGlobal: [soar.cts] ignore the status update of camera: 302-14 00:17:19.400  1821  2663 W libc    : Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"02-14 00:17:19.400  1821  2663 W CameraManagerGlobal: [soar.cts] ignore the status update of camera: 402-14 00:17:19.400  1821  2663 W libc    : Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"02-14 00:17:19.400  1821  2663 W CameraManagerGlobal: [soar.cts] ignore the status update of camera: 502-14 00:17:19.400  1821  2663 W libc    : Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"02-14 00:17:19.400  1821  2663 W CameraManagerGlobal: [soar.cts] ignore the status update of camera: 602-14 00:17:19.401  1821  2663 W libc    : Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"02-14 00:17:19.401  1821  2663 W CameraManagerGlobal: [soar.cts] ignore the status update of camera: 702-14 00:17:19.401  1821  2663 W libc    : Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"02-14 00:17:19.401  1821  1882 W libc    : Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"02-14 00:17:19.401  1821  1882 W CameraManagerGlobal: ignore the torch status update of camera: 202-14 00:17:19.402  1821  1882 W libc    : Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"02-14 00:17:19.402  1821  1882 W CameraManagerGlobal: ignore the torch status update of camera: 302-14 00:17:19.421  1821  1882 W libc    : Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"02-14 00:17:19.421  1821  1882 W CameraManagerGlobal: ignore the torch status update of camera: 502-14 00:17:19.421  1821  1882 W libc    : Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"02-14 00:17:19.421  1821  1882 W CameraManagerGlobal: ignore the torch status update of camera: 602-14 00:17:19.476  1821  2656 W libc    : Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"02-14 00:17:19.606 25357 25378 W HidlServiceManagement: Waited one second for com.qualcomm.qti.uceservice@2.3::IUceService/com.qualcomm.qti.uceservice02-14 00:17:19.608   494  2668 W libc    : Unable to set property "ctl.interface_start" to "com.qualcomm.qti.uceservice@2.3::IUceService/com.qualcomm.qti.uceservice": error code: 0x2002-14 00:17:19.669  1821  2656 W CameraView: CameraViewModule::getAvailableCameraDevices took: 321 ms02-14 00:17:19.862  1821  2667 W libc    : Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.camera.privapp.list"02-14 00:17:19.905  1821  2665 E CameraManagerGlobal: Camera 5 is not available. Ignore physical camera status change02-14 00:17:19.916  1821  1965 E unknown:SoftAssertions: Unhandled SoftException02-14 00:17:19.916  1821  1965 E unknown:SoftAssertions: com.facebook.react.bridge.AssertionException: Expected to run on UI thread!02-14 00:17:19.916  1821  1965 E unknown:SoftAssertions:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.SoftAssertions.assertCondition(SoftAssertions.java:37)02-14 00:17:19.916  1821  1965 E unknown:SoftAssertions:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.UiThreadUtil.assertOnUiThread(UiThreadUtil.java:32)02-14 00:17:19.916  1821  1965 E unknown:SoftAssertions:     at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.resolveView(UIManagerModule.java:948)02-14 00:17:19.916  1821  1965 E unknown:SoftAssertions:     at com.mrousavy.camera.frameprocessor.FrameProcessorRuntimeManager.findCameraViewById(FrameProcessorRuntimeManager.kt:65)02-14 00:17:19.916  1821  1965 E unknown:SoftAssertions:     at com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)02-14 00:17:19.916  1821  1965 E unknown:SoftAssertions:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)02-14 00:17:19.916  1821  1965 E unknown:SoftAssertions:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)02-14 00:17:19.916  1821  1965 E unknown:SoftAssertions:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)02-14 00:17:19.916  1821  1965 E unknown:SoftAssertions:     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)02-14 00:17:19.916  1821  1965 E unknown:SoftAssertions:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)02-14 00:17:19.916  1821  1965 E unknown:SoftAssertions:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)02-14 00:17:19.916  1821  1965 E unknown:SoftAssertions:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)02-14 00:17:19.927  1556 23090 E CameraService: onTorchStatusChangedLocked: cannot get torch status of camera 1: No such file or directory (-2)02-14 00:17:19.928  1556 23090 E CameraService: onTorchStatusChangedLocked: cannot get torch status of camera 4: No such file or directory (-2)02-14 00:17:19.929  1821  1880 W libc    : Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"02-14 00:17:19.929  1821  1880 W CameraManagerGlobal: ignore the torch status update of camera: 202-14 00:17:19.929  1821  1880 W libc    : Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"02-14 00:17:19.929  1556 23090 E CameraService: onTorchStatusChangedLocked: cannot get torch status of camera 7: No such file or directory (-2)02-14 00:17:19.929  1821  1880 W CameraManagerGlobal: ignore the torch status update of camera: 302-14 00:17:19.929  1053  1333 W ISPHVX  : HalOp:OPEN+ lId:0 cId:002-14 00:17:19.929  1821  1880 W libc    : Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"02-14 00:17:19.929  1821  1880 W CameraManagerGlobal: ignore the torch status update of camera: 5
```

it always logged this line. `Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist`

and also this is one of build fingerprint error.

```
> 02-14 11:21:29.428  8542  8542 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
02-14 11:21:29.429  8542  8542 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone64_x86_64/emulator64_x86_64_arm64:12/S2B2.211203.006/8015633:userdebug/dev-keys'
02-14 11:21:29.441  8542  8542 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
02-14 11:21:29.441  8542  8542 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'x86_64'
02-14 11:21:29.441  8542  8542 F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2023-02-14 11:21:09.738929948+0530
02-14 11:21:29.442  8542  8542 F DEBUG   : Process uptime: 0s
02-14 11:21:29.442  8542  8542 F DEBUG   : Cmdline: com.abc
02-14 11:21:29.444  8542  8542 F DEBUG   : pid: 7135, tid: 8498, name: pool-14-thread-  >>> com.abc <<<
02-14 11:21:29.444  8542  8542 F DEBUG   : uid: 10148
02-14 11:21:29.444  8542  8542 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x3
02-14 11:21:29.444  8542  8542 F DEBUG   : Cause: null pointer dereference
02-14 11:21:29.444  8542  8542 F DEBUG   :     rax 0000000000000004  rbx 0000000000000000  rcx 000072b2d616ba10  rdx 0000000000000001
02-14 11:21:29.445  8542  8542 F DEBUG   :     r8  000072b1516af678  r9  00000000000000ac  r10 000072b1516aefa8  r11 000072b1a7d24ce8
02-14 11:21:29.445  8542  8542 F DEBUG   :     r12 0000000000000001  r13 000072b15aa68260  r14 000072b1a7dfe070  r15 ffff8d4e58201f8f
02-14 11:21:29.445  8542  8542 F DEBUG   :     rdi 000072b1516af678  rsi 0000000000000002
02-14 11:21:29.445  8542  8542 F DEBUG   :     rbp 0000000000000003  rsp 000072b1516af430  rip 000072b1bad3d280
02-14 11:21:29.445  8542  8542 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
02-14 11:21:29.446  8542  8542 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 00000000000bb280  /data/app/~~5LceSa2L9UH7l0rINZjSmw==/com.abc-RWaZWBcOMl5Z6_PJ-qvZtA==/base.apk!libc++_shared.so (BuildId: 0516d55561abea9d0a07bd4694edf00e363f9880)
02-14 11:21:29.446  8542  8542 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 00000000000bb07b  /data/app/~~5LceSa2L9UH7l0rINZjSmw==/com.abc-RWaZWBcOMl5Z6_PJ-qvZtA==/base.apk!libc++_shared.so (__gxx_personality_v0+123) (BuildId: 0516d55561abea9d0a07bd4694edf00e363f9880)
02-14 11:21:29.447  8542  8542 F DEBUG   :       #02 pc 0000000000231d44  /data/app/~~5LceSa2L9UH7l0rINZjSmw==/com.abc-RWaZWBcOMl5Z6_PJ-qvZtA==/base.apk!libreanimated.so (BuildId: 5cc729cfb31b745687777f760d09e5a1f3348457)
02-14 11:21:29.447  8542  8542 F DEBUG   :       #03 pc 0000000000231dde  /data/app/~~5LceSa2L9UH7l0rINZjSmw==/com.abc-RWaZWBcOMl5Z6_PJ-qvZtA==/base.apk!libreanimated.so (BuildId: 5cc729cfb31b745687777f760d09e5a1f3348457)
02-14 11:21:29.447  8542  8542 F DEBUG   :       #04 pc 00000000001ac11c  /data/app/~~5LceSa2L9UH7l0rINZjSmw==/com.abc-RWaZWBcOMl5Z6_PJ-qvZtA==/base.apk!libreanimated.so (facebook::jsi::Function::callWithThis(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Object const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long) const+172) (BuildId: 5cc729cfb31b745687777f760d09e5a1f3348457)
02-14 11:21:29.447  8542  8542 F DEBUG   :       #05 pc 00000000001b97f5  /data/app/~~5LceSa2L9UH7l0rINZjSmw==/com.abc-RWaZWBcOMl5Z6_PJ-qvZtA==/base.apk!libreanimated.so (BuildId: 5cc729cfb31b745687777f760d09e5a1f3348457)
02-14 11:21:29.447  8542  8542 F DEBUG   :       #06 pc 00000000001b9686  /data/app/~~5LceSa2L9UH7l0rINZjSmw==/com.abc-RWaZWBcOMl5Z6_PJ-qvZtA==/base.apk!libreanimated.so (BuildId: 5cc729cfb31b745687777f760d09e5a1f3348457)
02-14 11:21:29.447  8542  8542 F DEBUG   :       #07 pc 00000000001b95d3  /data/app/~~5LceSa2L9UH7l0rINZjSmw==/com.abc-RWaZWBcOMl5Z6_PJ-qvZtA==/base.apk!libreanimated.so (BuildId: 5cc729cfb31b745687777f760d09e5a1f3348457)
02-14 11:21:29.448  8542  8542 F DEBUG   :       #08 pc 00000000001b9543  /data/app/~~5LceSa2L9UH7l0rINZjSmw==/com.abc-RWaZWBcOMl5Z6_PJ-qvZtA==/base.apk!libreanimated.so (BuildId: 5cc729cfb31b745687777f760d09e5a1f3348457)
02-14 11:21:29.448  8542  8542 F DEBUG   :       #09 pc 00000000001b8712  /data/app/~~5LceSa2L9UH7l0rINZjSmw==/com.abc-RWaZWBcOMl5Z6_PJ-qvZtA==/base.apk!libreanimated.so (BuildId: 5cc729cfb31b745687777f760d09e5a1f3348457)
02-14 11:21:29.448  8542  8542 F DEBUG   :       #10 pc 0000000000036feb  /data/app/~~5LceSa2L9UH7l0rINZjSmw==/com.abc-RWaZWBcOMl5Z6_PJ-qvZtA==/base.apk!libjscexecutor.so (BuildId: 7179657edadbbd5b8c29994b3250e81c891dce63)
02-14 11:21:29.448  8542  8542 F DEBUG   :       #11 pc 00000000000cc1ca  /data/app/~~5LceSa2L9UH7l0rINZjSmw==/com.abc-RWaZWBcOMl5Z6_PJ-qvZtA==/base.apk!libjsc.so (BuildId: 18b38a5ee0eae09182d82130076d6c39e59b7128)
02-14 11:21:29.448  8542  8542 F DEBUG   :       #12 pc 0000000000342f94  /data/app/~~5LceSa2L9UH7l0rINZjSmw==/com.abc-RWaZWBcOMl5Z6_PJ-qvZtA==/base.apk!libjsc.so (BuildId: 18b38a5ee0eae09182d82130076d6c39e59b7128)
02-14 11:21:29.449  8542  8542 F DEBUG   :       #13 pc 000000000032ca9f  /data/app/~~5LceSa2L9UH7l0rINZjSmw==/com.abc-RWaZWBcOMl5Z6_PJ-qvZtA==/base.apk!libjsc.so (BuildId: 18b38a5ee0eae09182d82130076d6c39e59b7128)
```

The log displays another error `Cause: null pointer dereference`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately didn't receive any reply. There is no solution for now to this issue for me.

Anyways i found the root cause, that is the app crashed when scanning the bar code. as well as i have used `vision-camera-ocr` also. I removed the vision-camera-ocr for a while, and that's it. app works fine with barcode.

seems the issue, app is not working with barcode scanner and ocr both.. the issue is something with ocr library. Thanks!